# Speed improvement for sapply along a POSIX sequence

Tags: r, performance, time

I am iterating along a POSIX sequence to identify the number of concurrent events at a given time **with exactly the method described in this question** and the corresponding answer:

[How to count the number of concurrent users using time interval data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003333/how-to-count-the-number-of-concurrent-users-using-time-interval-data)

My problem is that my tinterval sequence in minutes covers a year, which means it has **523.025 entries**. In addition, I am also thinking about a resolution in seconds, which would make thinks even worse.

Is there anything I can do to **improve this code** (e.g. is the order of the date intervals from the input data (tdata) of relevance?) or do I have to accept the performance if I like to have a solution in R?

Comment: It seems that you could gain some speed by changing `tinterval`, `tdata$start` and `tdata$end` to "numeric" and applying the suggested (in the linked QA) solution on these.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using data.tables new `foverlaps` function. With the data from the other question:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tdata)
setkey(tdata, start, end)
minutes <- data.table(start = seq(trunc(min(tdata[["start"]]), "mins"), 
                                  round(max(tdata[["end"]]), "mins"), by="min"))
minutes[, end := start+59]
setkey(minutes, start, end)
DT <- foverlaps(tdata, minutes, type="any")
counts <- DT[, .N, by=start]
plot(N~start, data=counts, type="s")
```

[image: resulting plot]

I haven't timed this for huge data. Try yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that should be faster than processing a list. It relies on `data.table` joins and `lubridate` for binning times at closest minute. It also assumes that there were 0 users before you started recording them, but this can be fixed by adding a constant number to `concurrent` at the end:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

td <- data.table(start=floor_date(tdata$start, "minute"),
                 end=ceiling_date(tdata$end, "minute"))

# create vector of all minutes from start to end
# about 530K for a whole year
time.grid <- seq(from=min(td$start), to=max(td$end), by="min")
users <- data.table(time=time.grid, key="time")

# match users on starting time and 
# sum matches by start time to count multiple loging in same minute
setkey(td, start)
users <- td[users, 
          list(started=!is.na(end)), 
          nomatch=NA, 
          allow.cartesian=TRUE][, list(started=sum(started)), 
                                by=start]

# match users on ending time, essentially the same procedure
setkey(td, end)
users <- td[users, 
            list(started, ended=!is.na(start)), 
            nomatch=NA, 
            allow.cartesian=TRUE][, list(started=sum(started), 
                                         ended=sum(ended)), 
                                  by=end]

# fix timestamp column name
setnames(users, "end", "time")

# here you can exclude all entries where both counts are zero
# for a sparse representation
users <- users[started > 0 | ended > 0]

# last step, take difference of cumulative sums to get concurrent users
users[, concurrent := cumsum(started) - cumsum(ended)]
```

The two complex-looking joins can be split into two (first join, then summary by minute), but I recall reading that this way is more efficient. If not, splitting them would make the operations more legible.

Answer (score 0):

`R` is an interpretive language, which means that every time you ask it to execute a command, it has to interprete your code first, and then execute it. For loops it means that in each iteration of `for` it has to "recompile" your code, which is, of course, very slow.
There are three common way that I am aware of, which help solve this.

1. `R` is vector-oriented, so loops are most likely not a good way to use it. So, if possible, you should try and rethink your logic here, vectorizing the approach.
2. [Using just-in-time compiler.](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/04/speed-up-your-r-code-using-a-just-in-time-jit-compiler/)
3. (what I came to do in the end) Use `Rcpp` to translate your loopy-code in C/Cpp. This will give you a speed boost of a thousand times easy.